# discord bot adding reaction to message via python

Tags: python, bots, discord

I wanna make a bot react with the normal emojis to a message when a certain word is used in the message but I can't seem to find any solution that work for current version of discord.py. Can anyone help me with a format I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the documentation of [discordpy](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message). It shows there how to add a reaction to a message and has plenty of explanations (I attached the specific link to your problem).